# mailchimp api v.3 can't insert template_id on post campaigns

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

post campaigns

```
{
    "type" :"regular",
    "recipients": {
        "list_id": "0270xxxcf7"
        }
    ,
    "settings": {
        "subject_line": "Thank you for your reservation",
        "from_name": "Customer Service",
        "reply_to": "reception@xxxx.com",
        "template_id": 37125
    }
}
```

every time the response is with `["template_id"]=>int(0)`

I tried with php script and directly from "Developer Playground"... I got the same response.
Seems it's not possible to set the template id when you create a new campaign.

If I setup template_id: '37125' I receive this error:

> template_id must to be integer

I tried with intval(37125)....nothing, I got the same `["template_id"]=>int(0)` response.

Can somebody help me with this issue?

Comment: According with MailChimp help support: In 3.0, the campaign settings and the content of the campaign are split into two separate calls. This would explain why the template ID isn't being set when POSTing to the /campaigns/ endpoint. Once you've created that campaign, the template can be added by making a PUT request to /campaigns/{campaign_id}/content.

Using your example, the JSON for that call would look like this:

{
  "template":  {
           "id": 37125
            }
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the "Set campaign content" option

*/campaigns/{campaign_id}/content*

Comment: Please review [how to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please add some references and broaden your explanation.